# Randomly choosing between two options

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, random

i am very new to python and am trying to learn the language better. i am trying to create something very simple, i am playing around with *if* statements, i am trying to choose a random option and based on what is picked have a different response. what i have looks like this...

```
species = "cat" or "dog"
if species == "cat":
    print("yep, it's a cat")
else:
    print("nope, it's a dog")
```

but the outcome is always cat. how do i make it randomly choose?

Comment: The `or` operator in your first line stops evaluating as soon as one of the strings is evaluated as True. A string that contains data always evaluates as true. If you wanted "dog" from that first line, the first value would need to be false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `random` module and `choice` method on the list

```
import random

species_list = ["cat", "dog"]
species = random.choice(species_list)
if species == "cat":
    print("yep, it's a cat")
else:
    print("nope, it's a dog")
```